# Broken Sword Angel of Death

Tags: broken-sword-4

So Im playing Broken Sword: Angel of Death and am stuck. I read some walkthroughs and know what to do, unless Im missing something obvious...

Im at Hotel Alfonso and got the hotel flyer and spoke to Thelwell Minister.  I have no more speech options for him.  I go into the bathroom and call the hotel, which should allow me to ask for Thelwell Minister, but it never gives me the option.

Is this a bug?  Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sigh, I figured it out.  You have to *attempt* to open the doors protected by the keycard and fail.  Without this step, the necessary speech options do not appear.  I *had* done this, but the game froze.  I went to an earlier save, in which I hadnt done this step.

On a personal note, I find this poor design frustrating.  This game has several puzzles which *require* you to do things that really should be optional.